# Conda is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: anaconda, conda

[Command line screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bsJU.png)

I have successfully installed Anaconda on my drive D and added it to my path so that I am able to access it from *cmd* without using the Anaconda prompt.

However, after running *where conda* on the Anaconda prompt, I got the 3 different locations

**- D:\Anaconda\Library\bin\conda.bat**

**- D:\Anaconda\Scripts\conda.exe**

**- D:\Anaconda\condabin\conda.bat**

to set as paths but after doing that, the *conda* command on my command line still does not work.

Comment: `to set as paths but after doing that` <- what exactly have you done here? Have you edited the `PATH` environment variable? If so, whcih paths did you add?

Comment: @FlyingTeller yes I have edited the path environment variable.
- D:\Anaconda\Library\bin\conda.bat

- D:\Anaconda\Scripts\conda.exe

- D:\Anaconda\condabin\conda.bat

Above are the paths I added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error image and description of the issue, I can see that you have installed the `anaconda` in the `D:\` drive and tried to access it through the `C:\` drive.

To access the `conda` in **command prompt**, you need to run the below commands :

```
C:\Users\Loni Tande>cd D:\Anaconda\Scripts
D:\Anaconda\Scripts>conda
D:\Anaconda\Scripts>conda --version
```

Please make sure you have the latest `Anaconda` version installed in your system to access all its functionalities.